# How to set the font size for labels in pd.DataFrame.plot()? (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm wondering if it is possible to override the label sizes for a plot generated with `pd.DataFrame.plot()` method. Following [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) I can easily do that for the xticks and yticks using the `fontsize` kwarg:

> fontsize int, default None
> Font size for xticks and yticks.

Unfortunately, I don't see a similar option that would change the size of the xlabel and ylabel.
Here's a snippet visualizing the issue:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'date': '2020-09-10', 'value': 10},
        {'date': '2020-09-10', 'value': 12},
        {'date': '2020-09-10', 'value': 13},
    ]
)
df.plot(x='date', y='value', xlabel='This is the date.', ylabel='This is the value.', fontsize=10)
```

[image: Plot with fontsize=10]

```py
df.plot(x='date', y='value', xlabel="This is the date.", ylabel="This is the value.", fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Can I change the size of xlabel and ylabel in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) states, the result is a matplotlib object (by default, unless you changed it). Therefore you can change whatever you like in the same way you would change a matplolib object:

```py
from matplolib import pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel('This is the date.', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('This is the value.', fontsize=16)
```

You can keep changing the object as you wish using matplolib options.